# invalid file type error when upload zip file extension in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have a opencart 2.1.0.1 .
when i upload the zip file extension from extension installer
from admin panel it gives me "invalid file type error".

Comment: Not really programming related..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this issue just rename the extension such that it ends with .ocmod.zip. Example - you-extension-name.ocmod.zip.

Answer (score 1):

unzip the plugin then compress it with the same name and add `.ocmod.zip` as extension worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

extract your zip file, after extracting right click on the extracted folder and make it zip again and make sure to rename it with yourname.ocmod.zip
i.e type ocmod before .zip and save and upload.
hope this will help.

Answer (score -2):

Just add this in Settings>Server>MIME

application/zip
application/x-zip
application/octet-stream
application/zip-compressed
application/x-zip-compressed
application/x-compress